# change styles on elements when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a webpage with three sections elements and a navbar, i want to apply a style on the currently scrolled section (change the background-color of this section to black), how can i acheive this?

```html
 <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
        <div class="landing__container">
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
        <div class="landing__container">
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
          <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3">
        <div class="landing__container">
          <h2>Section 3</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: This is a post explaining [How to change the background color on Scroll](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_bg_gradient_scroll.asp)